# How to integrate $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}$?

I tried by using integration by parts, but always got sucked. Should be very easy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u = 1 -\sqrt x$, so that $$\mathrm du = -\frac 1 {2 \sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx \implies \mathrm dx = -2 \sqrt x\,\mathrm du = 2(u - 1)\,\mathrm du.$$ Then the problem is reduced to evaluating

$$\int \frac{\sqrt x }{1 - \sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx = \int \frac{1 - u}{u} \cdot 2(u - 1)\,\mathrm du.$$

Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Either amplify by the conjugate, or let $t=\sqrt x$.

Comment: What does amplify mean in this context?

Comment: Multiplying both numerator and denominator with a given number or expression. I don't know its exact English equivalent.

Comment: Oh Okay, sure no problem.  I thought it had a meaning I wasn't aware of.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $x=u^2$, $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}=-1+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x}}=-1+\frac{1}{1-u}$, then
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}dx}&=\int{\left(-1+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)(2udu)}\\
&=-\int{2udu}+2\int{\frac{u}{1-u}du} \\
&=-u^2+2\int{\left(-1+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)du} \\
&=-u^2-2u+2\ln|1-u|+C \\
&=-x-2\sqrt{x}+2\ln|1-\sqrt{x}|+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{ \sqrt{x}}{1 - \sqrt{x}} = - \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1} = - \int \frac{ \sqrt{x}-1+1}{\sqrt{x}-1}= - \int dx - \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

But, $ d( \sqrt{x} - 1) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x} } dx $. Hence

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}-1} = 2 \int \frac{\sqrt{x} d( \sqrt{x}-1)}{\sqrt{x}-1}=2 \int \frac{(\sqrt{x}-1+1) d( \sqrt{x}-1)}{\sqrt{x}-1} = 2 \int d( \sqrt{x}-1) + 2 \int \frac{ d(\sqrt{x}-1)}{\sqrt{x}-1} = 2 (\sqrt{x}-1) + 2 \ln(\sqrt{x}-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=z^2$. This works several times when there is a root under the integral.
$x=z^2 \Rightarrow dx=2zdz$

$\int \frac{\sqrt x}{1-\sqrt x}dx=2\int \frac{z^2}{1-z}dz$

Now write $z^2$ as $z^2-1+1=(z-1)(z+1)-1$

$=2\int \frac{(z-1)(z+1)-1}{1-z}dz=-2\int ((z+1)-\frac{1}{1-z})dz=-(z+1)^2-2ln(1-z)+c$